# how to print CreateTable(table) with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When I run `print CreateTable(question)` after the following code I get an error, and it is because it is not compiling correctly because of `ARRAY` which is something specific to postgres. How do I get it to compile the correct `CREATE` script? Where do I enter dialect-related compiling information?

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

metadata=MetaData()

user = Table('user', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
            )

question = Table('question', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('description', String),
            Column('answers', ARRAY(String))
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
print CreateTable(question).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())

CREATE TABLE question (
id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
description VARCHAR, 
answers VARCHAR[], 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```